# How to change the color of a Widget based on a different Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make simple app which displays `SvgPicture.assets()` and user can change the color of the `SvgPicture()` using color picker.

I have 2 widgets:

1. for displaying `SvgPicture()` called it *Svg.dart*
2. *main.dart* contains `BottomNavigationView`, and one of the tabs opens color picker, and the *Svg.dart*

I encountered some errors with `setState(() {})` but I managed to fix the error somehow but it does not change the color, when I tried changing the background color of `main.dart` it worked perfectly.

here is my code:

- `onItemTap()` method for the `BottomNavigationBar`

  ```
    void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (index == 0) {
      // First Tab
      }
      if (index == 1) {
      // SecondTab
      }
      if (index == 2) {
      // Third Tab
      }
      if (index == 3) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context){
            return AlertDialog(
              content:
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new ColorPicker(
                  pickerColor: Colors.red,
                  onColorChanged: (Color colorChanged) {
                    color = colorChanged;
             // (color) is assigned default value of Colors.red
             // here I'm trying to assign new value to (color)
                  },
                ),//ColorPicker
              ),//SingleChildScrollView
            );//AlertDialog
          });
      }
    });
  }
  ```
- then in `Svg.dart` I made another variable `Color picked = Colors.red` and assigned red as default value. this is how the `Svg.dart` widget code looks like:

  ```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      picked = main().createState().color;
    });
    return CustomMultiChildLayout(
      delegate: TempDelegate(
          position: Offset.zero
      ),
      children: [
        buildLayoutId(ids.shirtId, MyConstants.shirt, picked)
      ],
    );
  }
  LayoutId buildLayoutId(Object id, String item, Color color) {
    return LayoutId(
        id: id,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          item,
          color: color,
        ),
      );
  }
  ```

I tried looking for flutter documentations but I don't really know how/where the issue is, and did not find tutorials, Please help

**EDIT**

this is the `main.dart`

```
    class Main extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      _MainState createState() => _MainState();
    }
    
    class _Main extends State<Main> {
      int _slectedIndex = 0;
      Color color = MyConstants.darkWhite;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: Center(
            child: Svg(),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const<BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "",
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "",
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "",
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "",
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
            ],
            onTap: _onItemTap,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void _onItemTap(int index) {
        setState(() {
          if (index == 0) {
    // do something
          }
          if (index == 1) {
    // do something
          }
    
          if (index == 2) {
    // do something
          }
    
          if (index == 3) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context){
                return AlertDialog(
                  content:
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: new ColorPicker(
                      pickerColor: Colors.red,
                      onColorChanged: (Color colorChanged) {
                        setState(() {
                          color = colorChanged;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

and `Svg.dart`

```
class Svg extends StatefulWidget{
  //Color picked;
  @override
  SvgState createState() => Svg();
}

class SvgState extends State<Svg> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomMultiChildLayout(
      delegate: SvgDelegate(
          position: Offset.zero
      ),
      children: [
        buildLayoutId(ids.shirtId, MyConstants.shirt, CreateKit().createState().color)
      ],
    );
  }
  LayoutId buildLayoutId(Object id, String item, Color color) {
    return LayoutId(
        id: id,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          item,
          color: color,
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

the class that extends `MultiChildLyoutDelegate` for `CustomMultichildLayout` in `Svg.dart`

```
class SvgDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate{
  final Offset position;
  SvgDelegate({
    this.position
});
  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {

    Size leadSize = Size.zero;
    itemLayout(leadSize, size, ids.shirtId);
  }    
  void itemLayout(Size leadSize, Size size, Object id) {
    if(hasChild(id)){
      leadSize = layoutChild(
        id,
        BoxConstraints.loose(size),
      );
    }
  }    
  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(TempDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.position != position;
  }   
}
```

Comment: `color = colorChanged;` should be surrounded by setState if `svg` and `BottomNavigationBar` are in `main`. I think you don't need `picked` inside `svg`, the global variable `color` will do. Can you share the code for `main`?

Comment: can you share your full StatefulWidget code? btw, do not use `setState((){})` during build

Comment: @EdwardLi I applied the changes and I shared the edited code now please check it out.

Comment: @Gilang I'm not sure if understood you I'm noop lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flutter everything is a widget and you can create your own custom widgets.
Likewise, there are concepts such as hierarchy and state.

A stateless widget is a `StatelessWidget` such as a label, a background, a title or whatever.

A stateful widget is a `StatefulWidget` is something that changes such as a switch, an animated background, a page, etc. There is also an `InheritedWidget` but that is another topic.

`setState` is used in the `StatefulWidget` to update the state of **that** widget, to update a child from the parent, you can use the properties of the child.
When `setState` is called, it rebuilds the widget and its children if necessary.

The `Container` widget has a `color` property.

```dart
Container(
  color: colorParent,
)
```

Your custom widget can also have any property such as `color` or `size` or `colorChild`.

```dart
ChildWidget(
  colorChild: colorParent,
)
```

When you want to access the `colorChild` property of a `StatefulWidget` you use `widget.colorChild`, when it has no state, you can simply use `colorChild`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Parent(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ParentState createState() => ParentState();
}

class ParentState extends State<Parent> {

  // Define the color in parent
  Color colorParent = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [

            // Pass the color as a property

            ChildWidget(colorChild: colorParent),
            VerticalDivider(color: colorParent),
            Child2Widget(colorChild: colorParent),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Tap to Blue",
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Tap to Orange",
            icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: "Tap to Green",
            icon: Icon(Icons.palette),
          ),
          // ...
        ],
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTap(index) {
    // ...
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        setState(() {
          
          // Update color in parent
          colorParent = Colors.blue;
        });
        break;
      case 1:
        setState(() {
          colorParent = Colors.orange;
        });
        break;
      case 2:
        setState(() {
          colorParent = Colors.green;
        });
        break;
    }
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  // Define color in child
  final Color colorChild;

  const ChildWidget({Key key, this.colorChild}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ChildWidgetState createState() => ChildWidgetState();
}

class ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      // Use it
      color: widget.colorChild,
      child: Text('Child 1'),
    );
  }
}

class Child2Widget extends StatelessWidget {

  // Define color in child
  final Color colorChild;

  const Child2Widget({Key key, this.colorChild}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,

      // Use it
      color: colorChild,
      child: Text('Child 2'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you soo much man now I have better understanding of how flutter works. I have one more question to understand stateless/full, both stateless and statefull widget colors changes when colorParent changes, is it because `Parent` rebuilds on each tap with different color so the children widgets follows the parent and rebuilds? coz my understanding of stateless widgets that it builds once and that's it. thank you again for the explanation it's very helpfull

Comment: You are welcome!, and yes, you are right, a `statelessWidget` does not rebuild itself, that is, any internal action of the stateless does not rebuild it (that's why `MyApp` is Stateless), but in this case, there is an external `parent` agent that kills it (ouch!) and creates a new one. However, if you want to create a widget that is not rebuilt, you can add `const` before any widget (it is very useful for performance), but you can no longer pass variables in its parameters, only constants.

Answer (score 0):

please change the default picker color value, please assign the variable that contains any color value, and onTabItem change the value of the variable.

Color _color = Colors.red;

ColorPicker(pickerColor: _color, onColorChanged: (Color colorChanged) { setState(() => _color = colorChanged;},),